# PhoneGap geo: href to google maps

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, cordova

Im using PhoneGap to build an app. In this app I'want to create a geo link. PhoneGap does open a map with the right location on it, but the map is not Google Maps or Apple maps. Instead it opens a weird looking map.

I'm using AngularJS as a Framework

Right now I'm using this:

```
<a href="geo:53.33196,6.92583">View on Google Maps</a>
```

Is there a way that the app will open up the Google Maps downloaded from the Play Store?

Thanks!

Comment: on which device you are testing ? Android or Apple ?

Comment: I'm testing on Android first

Comment: Do you have Google Maps App installed on device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add the following to **config.xml**

```
<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

And try this:

1. Create a custom function in JS and use it to open default Maps App on the device

   ```
   var app = {
       initialize: function() {
       this.bindEvents();
   },         
   bindEvents: function() {
       document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
   },         
   onDeviceReady: function() {
       app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
   },
   openNativeAppWindow: function(data) {
       window.open(data, '_system');
   }
   ```

   };
2. The place where you are invoking Maps links then pass on your custom url with data and let it open the native browser window which in turn will push the native Maps App to handle the special urls.

**Few example:**

```
<input type="button" onClick="app.openNativeAppWindow('http://google.com')" value="Open Google"/>
            <br><br><a onClick="app.openNativeAppWindow('geo://0,0?q=dallas')" data-rel="external">google maps</a>
            <br><br><a onClick="app.openNativeAppWindow('geo:0,0?q=Bacau')">Geolocation Test</a>
            <br><br><a onClick="app.openNativeAppWindow('geo:0,0?q=34.99,-106.61(Treasure)')">longitude & latitude with a string label</a>
            <br><br><a onClick="app.openNativeAppWindow('geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway%2C+CA')">street address Test</a>
```

Comment: try this and let me know

Comment: It did the trick! I just edited the link to https://maps.google.com/ So I have more control over the map